# 'System.IO.IOException' when trying to delete .json files

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, io, ioexception

I'm trying to create a system to delete a set of folders, and in each folder there is a .json file (and a bunch of other files/subdirectories). However, everytime I try there's always a random .json file that can't be deleted since another process is accessing the file. Before anyone removes this post because it's been asked a lot, I've tried everything I read. I've tried setting the FileAttributes of the directories to normal (which worked when I had the same issues with other directories that didn't link to .json files), I've tried making the threads which access the directories background threads to make sure that none are still running after the application gets stopped, making sure the file explorer was closed before running the program, setting the File Access of each stream which saves each file to ReadWrite, disposing the StreamWriter that writes to the save (.json) file instead of closing it...*nothing* is working and I'm out of ideas. At this point it's *only* when deleting the .json files that I get this exception. What else am I missing?

The function that deletes each file of all types (nested functions are not a typo):

```
    public static void DeleteBrains()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resetting brains...");

        Dictionary<int, Thread> threads = new Dictionary<int, Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            DeleteDirProtector(i);
        }
        StartThreads(threads, false);
        
        void DeleteDirProtector(int i)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => DeleteDir(i));
            threads.Add(i, thread);
        }
        void DeleteDir(int i)
        {
            string CurrentDir = $@"{DebugFolderPath}\Brain {i}";
            if (Directory.Exists(CurrentDir))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleting Brain {i}...");
                File.SetAttributes(CurrentDir, FileAttributes.Normal);
                string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(CurrentDir);
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(CurrentDir);
                for (int j = 0; j < directories.Length; j++)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(directories[j], FileAttributes.Normal);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < files.Length; j++)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(files[j], FileAttributes.Normal);
                }
                Directory.Delete(CurrentDir, true);
            }
        }
```

The function that saves each .json file:

```
    public void SaveBrain(bool isUpdate)
    {
        BrainSaveString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
        string path = "";
        if (isUpdate)
        {
            path = BrainSavePath2;
        }
        else if (!isUpdate)
        {
            path = BrainSavePath;
        }
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            sw.Write(BrainSaveString);
            sw.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This probably isn't relevant, but here's the StartThreads() method:

```
    public static void StartThreads(Dictionary<int, Thread> threads, bool isBackground)
    {
        int threadCount = threads.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (threads[i].ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
                {
                    while (!StartThread(threads[i], false, isBackground)){}
                }
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }
        }
        while (threads.Count > 0) 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (threads[i].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
                    {
                        threads.Remove(i);
                    }
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: StartThread() (as requested):

```
    public static bool StartThread(Thread thread, bool ShouldRunAnyway, bool isBackground)
    {
        bool shouldStartThread = false;
        if (NumberOfThreads_ < NumberOfProcessors * 3)
        {
            shouldStartThread = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ShouldRunAnyway)
            {
                shouldStartThread = true;
            }
        }
        if (shouldStartThread)
        {
            thread.IsBackground = isBackground;
            thread.Start();
            lock (AllThreadsBeingUsed)
            {
                AllThreadsBeingUsed.Add(thread);
            }
        }
        
        return shouldStartThread;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried excluding the folder from AV scans?

Comment: @stuartd I guess that's the only thing I haven't tried

Comment: The code of StartThread procedure is missing. In what case does this procedure returns false ? If it returns false for a reason or another, the thread may be duplicated, but closed once.

Comment: @Graffito StartThread() checks whether the number of active Threads at any given time is less than three times the number of processors present on the computer in which the program is running on (my PC has 8, so 24 in my case). If there's less, it returns true, and creates a new thread to execute the next function. If there isn't less, unless I make an exception (which in this case i didn't), it returns false (and doesn't create a new Thread). It should only create a Thread once, then move on to the next Thread in the Dictionary. I'll post the code though.

Comment: You might try using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see which process is actually using the file

Comment: You can put in saveBrain a writeln() trace on the path to test if the json file you can't delete was not saved twice.